# How to send welcome email after user registers using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to send an email notification to user after registration using Devise. I had all mailer related files correctly set up and can send the emails correctly using rails console.

However, the code I wrote in Registrations Controller does not send email as I intend to.

I will be grateful for any advice on how to solve this. Thank you!

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
  end

  private
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    static_pages_welcome_path
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :broker, :buyer, :status)
  end
end
```

```
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'railsnewappnotificationaug2021@gmail.com'
  layout 'mailer'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to StockTradingApp')
  end
```

```
app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to StockTradingApp, <%= @user.email %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up for buyer account.<br>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
app/config/development.rb
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: 'railsnewappnotificationaug2021@gmail.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true }
```

```
logs
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for ::1 at 2021-08-26 21:28:17 +0800
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_error_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 41)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 114)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 5.2ms | Allocations: 1856)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 127)
  Rendered layouts/_notices.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 59)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 21.7ms | Allocations: 8245)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 28.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 14158)


Started GET "/users/sign_up" for ::1 at 2021-08-26 21:28:17 +0800
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_error_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 41)
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 106)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 6.6ms | Allocations: 1775)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 121)
  Rendered layouts/_notices.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 52)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 19.6ms | Allocations: 8070)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 20.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 8612)


Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2021-08-26 21:28:47 +0800
  [1m[35m (2.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC[0m
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ZwoUYUwl1YXuDfa8rhb3lIPfRgguEe+peM5VlrSKy2w7IsxI0U6hLps1F0DO6ou88q3Iq+5ZlqRcp7+aWVNl8w==", "user"=>{"email"=>"saoirxechen8596@gmail.com", "role_names"=>["", "broker"], "broker"=>"true", "buyer"=>"false", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  [1m[36mRole Load (1.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE (name IN ('','broker'))[0m
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:56:in `role_names='
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (1.5ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[36mUser Exists? (1.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "saoirxechen8596@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE User Exists? (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "saoirxechen8596@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Create (1.7ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "broker", "buyer", "status") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["email", "saoirxechen8596@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$12$4x1V3lOOwzWfZ8pw0gxUHu8BSApITAqSVcXR0ivyoh63Te39D.8ii"], ["created_at", "2021-08-26 13:28:47.845883"], ["updated_at", "2021-08-26 13:28:47.845883"], ["broker", true], ["buyer", false], ["status", "Pending"]]
  [1m[36mRoleUser Create (2.4ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "role_users" ("role_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["role_id", 2], ["user_id", 74], ["created_at", "2021-08-26 13:28:47.851990"], ["updated_at", "2021-08-26 13:28:47.851990"]]
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (8.9ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/static_pages/welcome
Completed 302 Found in 756ms (ActiveRecord: 38.9ms | Allocations: 375195)


Started GET "/static_pages/welcome" for ::1 at 2021-08-26 21:28:48 +0800
Processing by StaticPagesController#welcome as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering static_pages/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 74], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/static_pages/welcome.html.erb:1
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 74], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/static_pages_helper.rb:3:in `get_user_name'
  Rendered static_pages/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 15.0ms | Allocations: 3394)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 289)
  Rendered layouts/_notices.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 236)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 60.5ms | Allocations: 18385)
Completed 200 OK in 67ms (Views: 60.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms | Allocations: 20147)
```

Comment: You should probably move that above the `super`, try that and see if it runs then

Comment: Is there anything in the logs about it? Does any other mail get sent? What is the delivery_method? What's the UserMailer code?

Comment: @RockwellRice I tried and it is still the same. The registration just goes through successfully and there is no mention in the terminal about sending email or being unable to send email.

Comment: @matthew.tuck For the logs did you mean the ones printed on the terminal where I typed rails server? If yes, it only says that user is created in database and that relevant view templates are successfully rendered. No mention about being unable to send email. 
No other email gets sent. 
Delivery method is smtp. I have shared other files for the mailer code.

Comment: @sa0irxe Are you sure the controller is even getting used?  Look in your `/log/development.log` file, can you see that your controller is getting hit, or else what happens when a user is registering?

Comment: @RockwellRice based on the logs the Registrations Controller do get used. I edited and added the log entries.

Comment: Are you sure that your mailer's configuration is working? Can you try the following command  in the console and check if you receive the mail ?`UserMailer.welcome_email(User.last).deliver_now`

Comment: Hi I am sure my mailer is working using the rails console. Already mentioned this in the second sentence of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by moving the `UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver_now` in the model (`user.rb`) with callback `after_create`.